# Avoiding complete path of folder and Image not been shown in browser

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am making a web application using jsp and servlets .But am facing two problem that i have no ides how to remove :

Problem 1 : I am creating new folders in my WEB-INF folder .But what i want is that instead of giving full paths .I just provide relevant path Like :

```
File tempfilesstore = new File("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\SharedCrpto1\\web\\RetrievedFiles\\"+fileid+"-"+personname);

if(!tempfilesstore.exists())
tempfilesstore.mkdirs();
```

Can this full path be avoided as only path from web folder of the application is required.

Problem 2 : I keep a image in this folder by performing some operation on original image being browsed by the client on browser.

Now when i see the image in folder then it is present their But if i try to see the same image in browser it does not display the image .When i refresh my page for 3-4 times than sometimes it get displayed and sometimes after manually opening it by going to specified location.What can be reason for it ?Please help.

Here is how am trying to get image on browser :

```
<img src="RetrievedFiles/<%=path%>/<%=sharedfilee%>" alt="Image Preview Not Availablee" width="300" height="300" />
```

Here ,

```
String path=presentfileid+"-"+personname;
String sharedfilee=rs.getString("FILE_NAME");
```

Comment: View source in the browser and see what is inside the `src` attribute of the img tag, and correct accordingly.

Comment: @developerwjk The src is correct.If it was wrong then the image would not be displayed later on also.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in a JEE point of view, all files within the WEB-INF folder are not meant to be accessed by anyone but your server. It means that images, CSS files, javascript files, etc. in this directory will not be rendered by your web browser. Your JEE server will prevent that to happen.
So, in order to access files from your web browser, you need to put them outside the WEB-INF folder (at the same level, in a "images" folder, for instance).

For your first problem : Yes, you can use relative paths to instantiate files, using your classLoader.

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resourcePath")
```

or

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resourcePath")
```

depending on your needs. The first one returns a URI ([http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29)) whereas the second returns an InputStream ([http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)) that you can use with a FileInputStream.

The ressources are located in the classes folder, and the path is relative to the class your get the resource from. For example, you can use "/myImage.png" as a path to get the image at the root level.

Putting all your resources files in the "classes" folder (within subfolder if you want to) is a good architecture design.

For your second problem, you have mainly 2 solutions :

- if the image is rendered without any transformation, put it in a folder outside WEB-INF (see the beginning of my comment), and it will be visible from outside. In you JSP, you can access it like that :

  request.getContextPath() + "/" + sharedfile
- if the image needs a transformation, use a servlet instead

I hope that helps you.

Regards,
Alexandre FILLATRE